# SparkSQL:Cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN 'expression' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' due to data type mismatch:

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I get the type mismatch error when i use CASE WHEN in SparkSQL. Below is the error i get:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN q.`utama` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' due to data type mismatch: WHEN expressions in CaseWhen should all be boolean type, but the 1th when expression's type is utama#7L; line 3 pos 11;
```

I am using SparkSQL as following.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true") \
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()

results = spark.sql("""
SELECT q.ID_Propinsi_reg,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN q.utama THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END)AS utama,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN q.madya THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END)AS madya,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN q.muda THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END)AS muda,
       p.Nama
FROM
  (SELECT first(a.ID_Personal) as ID_Personal,
          CONCAT(a.ID_Personal, '', a.ID_Sub_Bidang) AS kode_ta,
          first(a.ID_Propinsi_reg) as ID_Propinsi_reg,
          first(a.ID_Kualifikasi) as ID_Kualifikasi,
          SUM(CASE
                  WHEN a.ID_Kualifikasi='1' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END)AS utama,
          SUM(CASE
                  WHEN a.ID_Kualifikasi='2' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END)AS madya,
          SUM(CASE
                  WHEN a.ID_Kualifikasi='3' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END)AS muda
   FROM temp_db.personal_reg_tt a
   GROUP BY 2) q
INNER JOIN lpjk_dwh.new_lpjk_propinsi p ON q.ID_Propinsi_reg=p.ID_Propinsi
GROUP BY 1

""")
results.show()
```

Whats wrong with the code? Is it something related to the data type of ID_kualifikasi column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `WHEN expressions in CaseWhen should all be boolean type, but the 1th when expression's type is utama#7L`. You need to have a boolean type in the `when` expression. You can try casting it into a boolean by  `CASE WHEN CAST(q.utama AS BOOLEAN) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` etc.